# Any app for i18n of models for django in appengine or non-sql?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, internationalization, nosql

I'm working in a project with django and GAE, but I need internationalization for models, I try with [datatrans](https://github.com/citylive/django-datatrans) and [django-model-i18n](https://github.com/floledermann/django-model-i18n) but both applications make a heavy use of sql in databases and doesn't work with app-engine.

Theres is any application for i18n to model's level and work with non-sql databases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236153/google-app-engine-internationalization-help-needed-python

Comment: @zeekay is not the same question, i know how works i18n and i10n in django for static strings, but i need an app for models, "dinamic" data.

Comment: Ah good point. I guess that question doesn't cover the model field translation aspect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now, the most accurated project for work model field translation in app engine is [modeltranslation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/) because:

1. Add fields by language in the same table, and doesn't is a problem in app engine, perhaps in a SQL database.
2. This project 'hacks' AdminModel for show a special interface for i18n.
3. Has medium activity and is recent
4. For the translation in templates and views, don't make complex joins, just select.
5. Easy to install
6. In app engine works perfectly for make third party models translatables

Comment: would you tell me how did you adapt the django module to gae? I mean, modeltranslation works with fields of django, with a database different to the datastore. I tried to install it, but it doesnt make any change in my database. Could you help me please?

Comment: I use http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine and in that way i can use django models in GAE